# Serialization and deserialization of children

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

Let's assume I have the following structure:

```
abstract class foo{}
class bar1 extends foo{
     int demo1 = 0;
}
class bar2 extends foo{
     int demo1 = 0;
     int demo2 = 0;
}
class bar3 extends foo{}
```

Usually when I need to send a Json, I use the following code

```
Gson gson = new Gson()
gson.toJson(bar1);
```

*Recieving end*

```
Gson gson = new Gson()
bar1 test = gson.fromJson(gsonString, bar1);
```

The issue here is that I need to send bar1/bar2/bar3 and get back the original object - **Meaning I don't know what the current JSON should be parsed back into**. Another layer of complexity is added due to the fact that an array of bar1/bar2/bar3 are being sent back.

Ex:

```
//Issue: is the second param bar1 bar2 or bar3?
//I put a questionmark where the issues occur, due to the fact 
//that I wouldn't know on the recieving side whether I'm going 
//to recieve bar1/bar2/bar3
? test = gson.fromJson(gsonString, ?);
```

I tried storing the type in foo, but without being able to parse it back there is no way to know the type.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. `GSon.fromJson()` returns a value which you are ignoring, so how can there possibly be a problem as to what class it is?

Comment: I'm not ignoring it! Depending on the object in the paramaters, it gives back that object. The problem is that I don't know what object the Json recieved represents.

Comment: `gson.fromJson(gsonString, bar1);` does not store the result into a variable, *ergo* it ignores it.

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding the problem, so I updated the question and stored it in a value. It's not what I'm asking, please read the whole question(or at least the bold part).

Comment: You can atleast get a `foo`. Also, why do you want a club three different types at reception. I'd suggest that you keep them separate. That way you dont have to worry about the type because you'll know what it is.

Comment: I can't really change the problem @Gurwinder :/ .As for getting foo, the attributes of bar1 and bar2 are lost if I parse to foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the type in Foo like this:

```
private String fqcn;
```

The you could do first a string search on the json string when receiving, to extract the fully qualified classname. Then you can use:

```
Foo test = gson.fromJson(gsonString, Class.forName( foundFqcn);
```